# The set of function being countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am confused with the following notation for the set:
$$\{\ f:A \to B\}$$
How such a set is interpreted? Does this even make sense to refer to this as a set? Is it a set whose member is a function? And how can we make any claim about this set being countable or uncountable? I am not referring to any specific sets $A$ and $B$, but I am looking for some instructive ideas.

Comment: This notation usually represents the set of mappings from $A$ to $B$. If you don't have any information about $A$, $B$, or $f$ then you can't know if it is countable or not

Comment: Function sets are uncountable if the domain is uncountable and the codomain contains at least two elements. I think there are bunch of answers on your questions in this site.

Comment: That was really informative. I will try to prove that.

Comment: @HanulJeon: The set is uncountable as soon as the domain is _infinite_ and the codomain contains at least two elements.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Good point, thank you.

Comment: @RobG: Would you understand it better if the set was written $\{f\mid f:A\to B\}$? Or perhaps even $\{f\subseteq A\times B \mid f:A\to B\}$?

Comment: Another notation for the same set is $B^A$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes that helps! Thanks for all the good points you all made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite notation for this is $Y^X$.  See *functional analysis*.

As mentioned by @Henning Makholm, the space is uncountable as soon as $X$ is infinite and $Y$ has at least $2$ elements. 
This follows from Cantor's diagonal argument.